# Confused about ping replies from Apache web server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, ping

I have a Raspberry Pi running Apache web server. I have configured it to run multiple sites - these are local only, they are not internet facing yet.

I have updated my host file on my Ubuntu laptop with the domains and IPs.

When I ping say domain1 I get a reply from domain1.

When I ping domain2 I still get a reply from domain1.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apache is not involved in your question at all. It does not respond to ICMP Echo Request.

ICMP is not concerned with host names, only with IP addresses.

The `ping` program will usually attempt to resolve a name for the IP address it has resolved the command line argument to:

1. `ping domain2`
2. domain2 resolves to 192.168.123.123
3. 192.168.123.123 resolves to domain1
4. `ping` displays domain1 as responding

Example:

```
$ ping -c 1 google.com
PING google.com(fra15s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:81c::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra15s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:81c::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=12.3 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.333/12.333/12.333/0.000 ms
```

Comment: I see now, thank you Daniel B for your reply.